# can't uninstall python 3.9.x on Window 10

Tags: python

I noticed that I installed the wrong version of python (3.9.9), so I tried to uninstall python on Apps & features tab.

[image: 1]

Popup Windows says 'Uninstall was successful', but whole files are still left in the installation path(...\Programs\Python) and apps list.

Repair >> Uninstall process, verison upgrade(3.9.12) >> Uninstall process didn't work either.

So, How do I completely remove Python?

Comment: How did you install Python? It's common to have multiple Python versions on a system (not just on Windows) so different installation methods can end up installing different versions in different locations. The App Store installs one version, Conda another, and if you use the official Python installer you get another. Virtual environments can have their own versions too.

Comment: by official Python installer(from python.org, exactly)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue just now and found that I had to repair that version of python before I could uninstall it.

1. Open the system Control Panel > Programs and Features
2. Find the version of Python you want to uninstall
3. Right-click > Change (not Uninstall)
4. The Python Setup window will open and you want to select Repair.
5. Let it run until complete. At which point you should be able to return the Programs and Features window and uninstall

I just cleared out a handful of version that I must have tried to manually delete at some point which likely caused this issue in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

1.Type Control Panel in the taskbar on your desktop or ask Cortana to open the Control Panel.
2.Click on Programs, then open Programs and Features.
3.Find the program you want to uninstall and right-click on it.
4.Select the Uninstall or Uninstall/Change button, whichever appears.

Here you can remove Python fully from your computer and you can install another version or whatever you want!

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but faild :'(

Comment: try to find the folder in local disk c for example where you save it and delete it from there